# Warmup steps in deep learning

Tags: optimization

What do warm steps and warmup proportion mean? how to select the number of warmup steps?

Learning rate changes for each batch or each epoch for warmup step=1 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In the context of Deep Learning, what is training warmup steps](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/55991/in-the-context-of-deep-learning-what-is-training-warmup-steps)

Comment: I got it but my question is warm step mean per batch or per layer or per epoch?

Answer (score 3):

Answering your four questions

1. **Warm up steps:** Its used to indicate set of training steps with very low learning rate
2. **Warm up proportion ($wu$):** Its the proportion of number of warmup steps to the total number of steps
   3 Selecting the number of warmup steps varies depending on each case.

   - [This research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.07705.pdf) discusses warmup steps with 0%, 2%,
     4%, and 6%, which are all reflect significantly fewer warmup steps than in BERT.
   - This particular user had better performance with warmup steps of 165k. [Kindly refer to this forum](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/649)
3. As per [this deep-learning documentation](https://peltarion.com/knowledge-center/documentation/modeling-view/run-a-model/optimization-principles-(in-deep-learning)/learning-rate-schedule) its *warmup per epoch*

[image]

**References**:

- [Research paper which discusses on warm steps and warmup proportion](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.07705.pdf)
- [How to choose warm-up steps depending on the train steps during pre-training?](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/369)
- [deep-learning documentation on learning rate schedule](https://peltarion.com/knowledge-center/documentation/modeling-view/run-a-model/optimization-principles-(in-deep-learning)/learning-rate-schedule)

Answer (score 2):

I will quote from several well-explaining resources.

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/es9qv7/d_warmup_vs_initially_high_learning_rate/).

> a) Warm-up: A phase in the beginning of your neural network training
> where you start with a learning rate much smaller than your "initial"
> learning rate and then increase it over a few iterations or epochs
> until it reaches that "initial" learning rate.

Another nice [explanation](http://Warmup%20is%20a%20method%20of%20warming%20up%20learning%20rate%20mentioned%20in%20ResNet%20paper.%20At%20the%20beginning%20of%20training,%20it%20uses%20a%20small%20learning%20rate%20to%20train%20some%20epoches%20or%20steps%20(for%20example,%204%20epochs,%2010000%20steps),%20and%20then%20modifies%20it%20to%20the%20preset%20learning%20for%20training.). This one also has an example code and graph.

> Warmup is a method of warming up learning rate mentioned in ResNet
> paper. At the beginning of training, it uses a small learning rate to
> train some epoches or steps (for example, 4 epochs, 10000 steps), and
> then modifies it to the preset learning for training.

Now, carefully read this one from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340311/what-is-the-difference-between-steps-and-epochs-in-tensorflow):

> A training step is one gradient update. In one step `batch_size` examples are processed.
> An epoch consists of one full cycle through the training data. This is
> usually many steps. As an example, if you have 2,000 images and use a
> batch size of 10 an epoch consists of:
>
> 2,000 images / (10 images / step) = 200 steps.

Comment: So the steps mean the number of batches or optimization steps, not the number of epochs?

Comment: @CyberPlayerOne that is correct. A training step refers to processing one batch of images in that example and updating the model's parameters based on the calculated gradients.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm still confused though. Because in PyTorch's doc, it states "`torch.optim.lr_scheduler` provides several methods to adjust the learning rate based on the number of **epochs**." (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html). Maybe both training batches or epochs can work for LR scheduler to adjust LR in them?